# Is there a standard dummy executable file that does nothing in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

Is there a standard dummy executable file that does nothing in Linux? I have a shell command that always opens $EDITOR before the build process to input arguments manually. In my case, my arguments are always already set (this is an automated script) so I never need it, but it still pops up and awaits user input.

To solve this, I created an empty executable file that does nothing, so I can set `EDITOR=dummy` and the build script calls it, it exits and the build process can start.

My question is, is there an existing official file in Linux that when executed does nothing, a sort of placeholder that I could use for this purpose?

Comment: Can't you just do `unset EDITOR` or `EDITOR=""` instead?

Comment: @terdon: well if you want to open `ed` or some other silly default.

Comment: @terdon, afaik most programs have some fallback, `ed` or `vi` perhaps. E.g. less's man page says it takes the editor from "environment variable VISUAL if defined, or EDITOR if VISUAL is not defined, or defaults to "vi" if neither VISUAL nor EDITOR is defined." (Except in Debian it might default to `/usr/bin/editor` or such.) I think I've also seen shell scripts with  `${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}}` or similar. But seldom anything that would just forgo all editing for users that haven't set `EDITOR` in their startup files.

Comment: @terdon no, because the actual invocation done by the build system is $EDITOR /path/to/file. When doing EDITOR="", it tries to execute the build file directly.

Comment: Ah, ouch. Yeah, that's no good.

Comment: I so tempted to answer `yes`.

Comment: @talex Is an utility that generates some (a lot of) output a valid solution?

Comment: @Isaac no, that is why I didn't.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

There's the standard utilities `true` and `false`. The first does nothing but [return an exit status of 0 for successful execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/true.html), the second does nothing but return a non-zero value indicating a non-successful result<sup>(*)</sup>. You probably want the first one.

Though some systems that really want you to enter some text (commit messages, etc.) will check if the "edited" file was actually modified, and just running `true` wouldn't fly in that case. Instead, `touch` might work; it [updates the timestamps of any files it gets as arguments](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/touch.html).

However, if the editor gets any other arguments than the filename `touch` would create those as files. Many editors support an argument like `+NNN` to tell the initial line to put the cursor in, and so the editor may be called as `$EDITOR +123 filename.txt`. (E.g. `less` does this, `git` doesn't seem to.)

---

Note that you'll want to use `true`, not e.g. `/bin/true`. First, if there's a shell involved, specifying the command without a path will allow the shell to use a builtin implementation, and if a shell is not used, the binary file will be found in `PATH` anyway. Second, not all systems have `/bin/true`; e.g. on macOS, it's `/usr/bin/true`. (Thanks @jpaugh.)

<sub>(* or as the [GNU man page puts it](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/false.1.html), false "[does] nothing, unsuccessfully". Thanks @8bittree.)</sub>

Comment: That must be `/bin/true`. Otherwise it would usually be a shell builtin which is not really "a standard dummy executable file".

Comment: @HaukeLaging, yes... in practice. The build process or whatever probably doesn't run through the shell, so it'll end up picking `/bin/true` from the path. Or if it picks the shell builtin, it doesn't really matter. But if I've understood correctly, the standard doesn't really define that it has to be found specifically as `/bin/true`.

Comment: The standard allows `true` and `false` to be shell builtins but it also requires the commands to be available as executable files in the standard search `PATH`.

Comment: In SysV Unix, /bin/true was a shell script that contained nothing but a copyright comment. Not sure what they are copyrighting...

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Hilarious; HP-UX had #!/sbin/sh and : in the script (or was it exit 0; it's been a terribly long time). Same basic idea; the copyright notice is most of the thing being copyrighted.

Comment: @Joshua, you just need a file that contains the hashbang. A shell script with no commands has exit status 0. Or if it's going to be launched with `exec*p()`, an empty file would do since those functions must run the file through the shell if the low-level `execve()` call returns `ENOEXEC` to signal that it's not in a known executable format. (as far as I've understood, that logic is something like a precursor to hashbangs.)

Comment: Why not `EDITOR=test` ? A `test /path/to/file/` will have no output and an exit code of 0 (for a non NUL file path).

Comment: @Isaac, does `test` have any advantage over `true`? What I should have mentioned with `touch` already, is that many editors support a `+NNN` argument to tell the line number where to initially put the cursor. Run `$EDITOR +123 file.txt` and `test` will croak, `touch` will create an extra file, and `true` will return `0`. I didn't know if they have that here, and e.g. `git` doesn't seem to use it, it leaves space for the commit message at the top of the file (with comments below). Ok, `test` would croak if the filename is null but that likely would cause problems for the rest of the script too.

Comment: @ilkkachu Not much if both are available. But `test` seems like hard to be missing a `test` executable. I have the impression that `true` could be missing in some cases. There are more options than `true`, `test` and `touch`. Please [read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597526/232326). Using `printf ''` would be wonderful if it were possible to set the first argument to NUL. Not sure how his build system works (he haven't said).

Comment: @Isaac, they said `$EDITOR /path/to/file` in another comment under the Q, so if it's without quotes like that, then yes, `test 1` would work. I don't know if there are systems that would be missing one or the other as files. Anyway, unlike `cd`, those could actually be useful once in a while, and e.g. embedded Linuxes deal with it by just linking to `busybox`. But I don't know.

Comment: Something using `execvp` to run an external program isn't going to be launching the `true` shell built in. The last remarks really spoil this answer.

Comment: @Kaz, yes, you're right. But we don't know how the build system works, if it is a shell script or a binary calling `exec*()` directly. And the poster said in a comment that _"the actual invocation done by the build system is `$EDITOR /path/to/file`"_, which looks like a shell command to me. The point of that last paragraph is that `true` works with both shell scripts, and with most binary utilities, since they're generally going to obey the path just so that the user doesn't need to specify `/usr/bin/emacs` but just `emacs` will do.

Comment: I do enjoy the (Gnu) manpages for `true`: "do nothing, successfully" and `false`: "do nothing, unsuccessfully." Doesn't that imply that `false` actually does do something? (Just to be clear, that is a rhetorical question. It is my understanding that `false` does nothing but exit with a non-zero status.)

Comment: @8bittree, hah yes, that's very cutely put in the man page. If we really get down to it, doing _absolutely_ nothing is impossible, the program must at least set some return value and call the syscall to exit. Or crash, but even that must be arranged somehow. :)

Comment: To explain @8bittree's joke - `false` unsucessfully does nothing, i.e. it tries to do nothing but fails in that attempt, i.e. it actually does something. (Pun on "unsuccessfully")

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Last time  I checked, the Solaris /bin/true shell script was at version 1.6 (it's been a few years). I wonder about the diffs between 1.6 and 1.5 or earlier.

Answer (score 27):

In the shell, you can use the built-in `:`.  It's not an executable file, but in a shell script or anything executed from a shell script it will do:

```
$ help :
:: :
    Null command.
     
    No effect; the command does nothing.
     
    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

This is perhaps best known for use in a while statement (`while :; do break; done`), but is not limited to such use.  In case you need to do this many times, it's much faster to not start a separate process:

```
$ time for i in $(seq 1000); do :; done

real    0m0,007s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,004s
$ time for i in $(seq 1000); do /bin/true; done

real    0m0,686s
user    0m0,462s
sys     0m0,217s
```

Comment: `:` will *not* work in many cases that expect to `exec` something. `/bin/true` will, though.

Comment: @JanHudec Correct, because `exec` is for starting a new process.  It may be that for OPs specific purposes, only `/bin/true` will work; but for others finding this question in the future, it may be that the shell builtin `:` is more appropriate.

Comment: @JanHudec, or just use `true` instead of `/bin/true` so if it's launched from a shell, you get the builtin, and from a non-shell the standalone executable can be found in `PATH`...

Comment: It's unlikely the script is using `exec`, as it would not be able to resume after the editor command exits.

Comment: @chepner, `exec(2)`, usually preceded by `fork(2)`, not `exec(1)`. If it's a script, it probably just runs a command, but the editor may not be started by the script directly, but rather by some other tool it wraps and that may or may not execute it by shell.

Comment: @JanHudec: `which :` yields `/bin/:` for me.

Comment: @Joshua, some systems have it, but not all of them. All should have `/bin/true`.

Comment: @gerrit: *"exec is for starting a new process"*: In a very pedantic sense this is not entirely correct. `exec` [runs an executable file in the context of an already existing process, replacing the previous executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)), no new process is started by `exec`. 
Of course  if you want the original executable to keep running in its own process, you first need to `fork()`, and *that* will create the new process..

Comment: @user000001, it's not even very pedantic, the distinction between fork() and exec*() is often quite important. As is the fact that unixes don't even have a single system call to launch a new process from a binary file, but you indeed have to start off by cloning the parent process.

Comment: @JanHudec, and I'll repeat what was mentioned under the other answers, it doesn't have to be `/bin/true`, it just needs to be in `PATH`.

Comment: @ilkkachu: there is `posix_spawn` (although other than embedded systems you may expect it to be a wrapper combining fork/vfork/clone and execve). Also, still in pedantic mode, the shell `exec` can do other things other than executing files (it changes the fd on the current process).

Comment: @Ángel, ah right, there was that one. I know what the shell's `exec` does, that's why I specifically said `exec*()` and not just `exec` :)

Comment: @user000001 Ah, I didn't know, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

@ilkkachu's suggestion of using the `true` command is probably the best answer, but you could also use the command

```
sleep 0
```

Comment: I didn't suggest `/bin/true`, but `true` (without a path).

Comment: For the record, on my system, `which true` returns `/usr/bin/true`, so ikkachu's distinction of whether to supply the path is important.

Comment: @jpaugh, hah! It's indeed in `/usr/bin` on macOS, why didn't I check it before.

Comment: There are probably lots of commands one could post that ignore their arguments and return immediately; not every one of them needs their own answer.

Comment: @jpaugh To add to that record, you may be on an Arch Linux (or one of its derivatives), where `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @rexkogitans Zoiks! I'm actually on MSYS2, which chose pacman as the package manager, so that's a pretty good guess. Symlinks require admin rights on Windows, so it's probably a straight copy.

Answer (score 3):

There are several **do nothing** solutions in a shell. Most notably `:`, a [POSIX required **null** utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#colon).

But you also require that it is an external **file**.

So: the POSIX standard specified dummy executable files that do nothing could be:

1. Utilities that output nothing and their exit status is **success** (0) (except were noted) (in order of relevance (IMO):

```
printf ''             # requires a format. The format may be empty.
test 1                # requires a non-empty string (or number).
[ 1 ]                 # equivalent to test.
true                  # requires no argument.
false                 # requires no argument (exit code IS 1 ).
rm -f ''              # DO NOT USE. requires a file name and will remove it.
sh -c ''              # may load init files into memory, not a clean solution.
                      # but it is almost unheard of that `sh` is missing.
                      # sh -c '' /path/to/file will not damage the file.
```

2. Utilities that also end on an exit code of `0` but have some output:

```
echo ''
date +''
expr ''
```

There may be others ?. [search yourself list of executables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html)

But your query also specify (If I understand you correctly) that the called executable is compatible with:

```
> the actual invocation done by the build system is $EDITOR /path/to/file
```

That seem to imply that the executable should not use any argument, or, accept one argument and do nothing to it.

I do not know the exact details of your build system, but probably a:

```
test /path/to/file
```

Given that `EDITOR` is set to `test` should work perfectly fine (or true, or false).

If some output is not a problem (the build system discard the output of the `EDITOR`), then `echo` or `printf` may be suitable also.

Comment: Just `echo` without any arguments should also do (it still outputs the newline, of course)

Comment: I think many of the examples are like "Build 0 houses".

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Oh, sure, that is true. But isn't that what the OP asked for?

Comment: He wants an executable file, according to the title. Like `/bin/true` is. (`true` in an interactive shell does not use the file) All of your examples exist as executable files too: There is even a file `/bin/[` - it complains if it does not get the argument `]`. Right, there is some redundancy in the examples, but that's not a problem.

Comment: Reading the examples again, I think the example `rm -f ''` should be removed. The `-f` makes it more dangerous than just an `rm`, You can alias `rm` to `rm -i`, making `rm` interactive, asking you before removing a file. That would result in `rm -i -f ''`, the safety gets canceled by forcing. I do like the examples `rm` and `sh` somehow, and there is some academic value in having them. You even describe the problems - I had missed that `/bin/sh` reads files, also libs. By now, I feel these examples should not be there, even if a reader could learn a lot by understanding them. I'll remove them.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I understand your concerns, and mostly agree with them. However, the answer does say **DO NOT USE** in caps for `rm`. The `-f` avoids an error emitted, `rm -f ''` doesn't complain of an empty file name, but `rm ''` does. Making `rm` interactive won't work. The OP will apply to an external building system that might execute `$EDITOR /path/to/file` without any interactivity expected. The detail that `sh -c` **might** read additional files is also mentioned already in the answer. So, overall, I believe that both are valid solutions. Not meant for inexperienced users, of course.

Answer (score 0):

## `/bin/true`

`true` does nothing successfully.

`false` attempts to do nothing, but fails.

They are implemented in `/bin/true` and `/bin/false`.

But because it's sometimes good to do nothing really fast, there is also a shell builtin `true`.
Sometimes you want to fail with doing nothing really fast, so there is a shell builtin `false`.

The difference between succeeding and failing is the exit status `$?`. It is `0` for success and anything other than that for failure. Exit status `1` is used to simply indicate failure, but it can be an error code up to `254` to explain what went wrong in detail.

```
$ true
$ echo $?
0
$ false
$ echo $?
1
$ false
$ echo $?
1
$ echo $?
0
```

Note how the last `echo` returns `0` because the `echo` preceding it succeded.

The exit status is used with the logic operators, like "and" (`&&`) and "or" (`||`):

```
$ true && echo "success"
success
$ false && echo "failure"
$ true || echo "success"
$ false || echo "failure"
failure
```

Note how after `false && echo "failure"` and `true || echo "success"` nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for a more general case where *nothing* can mean multiple things. When it means:

- Stopping with a "normal" return code you can use the suggestions mentioned in all other answers
- Stopping without return code: Not possible
- Avoiding a return code by just never stopping `sleep 100000d` should work for a couple of centuries
- Not handling when it receives signals: Not possible, some signals can't be blocked (e.g. `SIGKILL`)
  (In theory something similar is possible by creating a [forkbomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb), but you do **not** want that)